# What does the colour coding of Google Chrome Inspect Element signify?

Tags: html, google-chrome, colors, tags, inspect-element

When I inspect Google Chrome, I can see that the Elements panel colour codes certain html tags in one colour and other words in different colours.

At https://www.google.co.uk/, I can see that, for example,

1) div is coloured in violet

2) id is coloured in brown

3) pocs is coloured in navy blue

Can anyone tell me what these colours signify? Does

1) violet indicate element

2) brown indicate attribute

3) navy blue indicate value

?

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Chrome used these colours to differentiate between the elements,attribute and attribute's value.

these colours signifies exactly as you said

1) violet indicate element
2) brown indicate attribute
3) navy blue indicate attribute's value.